# jooq alias on join tables

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I have 2 joined SQL tables :

```
CREATE TABLE "B" (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    lastname TEXT
```

);

```
CREATE TABLE "A" (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    firstname TEXT,
    b_id BIGINT REFERENCES "B"(id),
);
```

And I would like to request it to fill data into this object :

```
public class A {
    public long id;
    public String firstname;
    pulic String lastname;
}
```

with a request looking like that :

```
SELECT A.id AS id, A.firstname AS firstname, B.lastname AS lastname FROM A JOIN B ON a.b_id = B.id WHERE A.id = 42
```

However, I don't know how to set an alias for the SQL field `lastname` of table `B` to be able to fill the object attribute `lastname` in the class `A`?

Is it possible to do it at all? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to alias your column if it already matches the property in your target class. While the columns in an [`org.jooq.Result`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Result.html) may originate from a table `A` or from a table `B`, the [`DefaultRecordMapper`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DefaultRecordMapper.html) will only consider individual column names for mapping. It doesn't matter how you produced those column names.

[A related discussion on the jOOQ User Group can be seen here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jooq-user/oSSnjuGz1Lc).

So the following query will work right away:

```
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(A.ID, A.FIRSTNAME, B.LASTNAME)
   .from(A)
   .join(B).on(A.B_ID.eq(B.ID))
   .where(A.ID.eq(42))
   .fetchInto(A.class)
```

Of course, if you feel you need full control over the column names that are generated in your SQL, simply alias them using [`Field.as()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#as-java.lang.String-):

```
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(
        A.ID.as("id"), 
        A.FIRSTNAME.as("firstname"), 
        B.LASTNAME.as("lastname"))
   .from(A)
   .join(B).on(A.B_ID.eq(B.ID))
   .where(A.ID.eq(42))
   .fetchInto(A.class)
```